# Formatting time in Android Application

Tags: java, android, time, calendar

I've created an Android grading app to use within my classes. All the database connections and grading logic has been laid out and functions precisely as it should.

However, I am having a problem incorporating the Java Calendar class. I need to be able to limit each class to submit their answers "only" during their class time. As you can see, I will need to incorporate a series of "if statements" in order to do this.

The problem is that I don't know how to get this time that I need to verify that my student's answer submissions are only handled during their class time.

This is what I've tried:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

As you can see, I am only able to get hours and minutes separate from each other. How do I get the real time? Just Hours and minutes not seconds.

In my code my set up should look like this:

```
int period = will be selected from a spinner object

if(period == 1 && (time>= 7:20 AM && time<= 9:00AM)) Then, go ahead and 
submit your answers to online database.

if(period == 8 && (time>= 12:50PM && time<= 2:20PM)) Then, go ahead and 
submit your answers to online database.
```

I don't know how to format this "time" object with the Calendar class.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated to the question but some smart student can change the date/time on their device and submit outside of the window.

Comment: Well that's possible. Since they are submitting answers to an online database, I could probably create a column value in the database that creates a time stamp as to when the answer was submitted. Checking on this time will tell me the real time It was submitted. I don't know how to get the current time in 24 hour format from PHP. @iceman

Answer (score 1):

You can set hours and minutes to the calendar:

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
start.set(Calendar.HOUR, 7);
start.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
```

The same for the `endDate`:

```
Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
end.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);
end.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
```

To check that the current datetime is in the interval:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();//now
boolean isInInterval = cal.getTime().after(start.getTime()) && cal.getTime().before(end.getTime());
```